# Magento 2 static content deploy duplications

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have Magento 2 installation with a lot of websites and one website has language which other websites don't. When I execute setup:static-content:deploy it generates the language for all store views I have. It's strange behavior, I think it should generate this language only for a particular website and store view, isn't it? Any thoughts on this? Magento 2.4.6-p2.

P.S. To add an exclude theme parameter to setup:static-content:deploy isn't a solution for me, because I need to solve it globally.

Comment: you need to pass all language in argument with deploying `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB en_AU` and so on will resolve your issue i think by default it will deploy en_US only

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass languages seperately in argument while deploying like below cli command

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB en_AU es_ES`

It will resolve your issue, by default it will deploy `en_US` only.